# jquery listing HTML elements inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used setinterval to slide number of divs every period of time and that worked fine but the problem happend when i made function"getdata()" that testing this animation and returns the width,left postion,text inside Div for each p...please help me to improve the function "getdata()" to get these information about each p which it changes per sec or i value.
ineed to view data like that
    **1,left is:0,width:60

    2,left is:34,width:40

    3,left is:66,width:70**

I want to make the data_text which is "1 or 2 or 3" is fixed while the width & data_p_l changes for each data_text "u can consider it it's an ID for the element" 4Ex "

**1,left is:0,width:60**

**1**>>           this is fixed and this line won't be repeated
**left is:20**>>  changing
**width:20**>>    changing

Ihopt that i've cleared my question.
Thanks alot.

The HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="center">
    <p id="th">3</p>
    <p id="s">2</p>
    <p id="f">1</p>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = null;
    var width = $('#center').width();
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('p').each(function() {
            $(this).css({'left': $(this).position().left + i});
        });
        getdata('p' ,'#test');   
        i+=1;  
    },500);  

function getdata(parentdiv,showdiv){
$(parentdiv).each(function(){
var $this = $(this);    
var width = $this.width();
var data_p_l= $this.position().left;
var data_text= $this.text();
var dataset = data_text + ",Left value is: "+ data_p_l + ",
width value is: "+  width ;//+ ",id value is: "+ data_id;
$(showdiv).text($(showdiv).text() + ' ' + dataset); 
});} 
});
```

Comment: indentation would make you code more readable ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but This might help. First in this section:

```
function getdata(parentdiv,showdiv){
        $(parentdiv).each(function(){
            var len = $( parentdiv ).length;
            var width = $(e).width();
            var data_p_l= $(e).position().left;
            var data_text= $(e).text();
            var dataset = data_text + ",Left value is: "+ data_p_l + ",width value    is: "+ width;
            $(showdiv).text(dataset);
        });
    }
```

You want to replace `e` with `this`.

```
function getdata(parentdiv,showdiv){
    $(parentdiv).each(function(){
        var len = $( parentdiv ).length;
        var width = $(this).width();
        var data_p_l= $(this).position().left;
        var data_text= $(this).text();
        var dataset = data_text + ",Left value is: "+ data_p_l + ",width value    is: "+ width;
        $(showdiv).text($(showdiv).text() + ' ' + dataset);
            });
        }
```

Inside the `each` function, `this` is used to refer to each element that gets iterated over. At the end of your function, you are putting your results into your div with id `test`. However, this is running in a loop, so you will only end up with output for the last `p` tag, and not each one. What I think you want to do is add to the `test` div like this: `$(showdiv).text($(showdiv).text() + ' ' + dataset);`

Comment: thnx alot Brain for help, but this is not wat i need,look this made the result like this "3,Left value is: 103,width value is: 40 2,Left value is: 52,width value is: 40 1,Left value is: 1,width value is: 40 3,...I want to make the data_text which is "1 or 2 or 3" is fixed while the width & data_p_l changes for each data_text "u can consider it it's an ID for the element" 4Ex 1"this is fixed and this line won't be repeated">>left value:20"changing",width:20"changing"  ihopt that i've cleared my question.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. the output is in the same order as the `p` elements. That's why 3 comes first.